# How to have UTF-8 enconding with an Excel file with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, utf-8, openpyxl

With Python and Openpyxl, i have this result when i try to read the sheet name :

> [u'Janvier ', u'F\xe9vrier'

The code is :

```
self.classeur = openpyxl.load_workbook('/users/utilisateur/Desktop/Historique.xlsx')
print self.classeur.get_sheet_names()
```

What can I do to have Février ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `u'F\xe9vrier'`: this is Python 2's `repr` format, which always returns ASCII with escape sequences. `u'Février'` and `u'F\xe9vrier'` are the same string, just shown differently.

Comment: I try with repr() but it's the same output.  How convert my string in  u'Février' ?

Comment: You will never see `u'Février'`. On Python 3, `repr()` will return `'Février'`, so consider upgrading (for many more reasons, actually). In any case, maybe this produces what you want: `print ', '.join(self.classeur.get_sheet_names())`

Comment: The question asked in the post here has **nothing to do with** either the title or the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OOXML all strings are unicode. How these appear in your command line depends on a lot things but mainly the configuration of your computer. As the string is unicode you will need to convert it to the local encoding, assuming this can display the non-ascii characters.

Try:

```
print(s.encode("utf8"))
```

Note this only affects what you see. If you want to process the content or edit the file, just keep things as unicode.

Comment: If the default encoding is set up correctly and sufficient for the characters in `s`, then `print s` should be enough, since Python automatically encodes Unicode strings when printing. In the OP's case, however, a list is being printed, which calls `repr()` on each element. And `repr()` in Python 2 is all-ASCII for all built-in types, so you won't see any accented characters, using `encode()` or not.

Comment: The key question is "if". In Python 2 on many systems print can still lead to raise a `UnicodeDecodeError`

Comment: Definitely, and this doesn't change for using Python 3 (because Python can't do anything if the environment uses or communicates an insufficient codec/locale).